# How to fill data from a column from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the problem that I need to solve in sql managment studio 2017:
I have a database, two of the tables of these db are `Orden` and `Cliente`.

Table `cliente` has:

```
ClienteID-NumCedula-OrderID
```

Table `Orden` has:

```
OrderID-ProductoID-ClienteID
```

My problem is that I need to fill all the OrderiD (300 records) from the Order Table in the Cliente table, this table (cliente) has all Nulls in OrderID.
I need to fill all the records from Order.OrderID in the Cliente.OrderID

I tried some things that I find on the internet but it doesnt work.
Any ideas? 
Thank u so much :)

I tried some queries about UPDATE and INSERT INTO SELECT but nothing is working properly. Im new in all of the SQL db so its difficult sometimes.

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE(OrderID) 
SELECT OrderID FROM ORDEN;

UPDATE CLIENTE
SET    OrderID = ORDEN.OrderID
WHERE  CLIENTE.OrderID = ORDEN.OrderID;
```

A query or idea of ​​how to fill/update the records of Orden.OrdenID in cliente.OrderID

Answer (score 0):

As if you're looking for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause :

```
INSERT INTO 
   CLIENTE(OrderID)
SELECT o.OrderID FROM ORDEN o
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE OrderID = o.OrderID, ColC = o.ColO;
```

If there's a column ORDEN.OrderID's value which doesn't match with the CLIENTE.OrderID's value, then value inserted into CLIENTE table, otherwise updated.

*[ where CLIENTE.OrderID column is primary key, and assume ColC and ColO are extra columns to show update operation which's stated in the demonstration below ]*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3b81c22856b3f3ac3180ed1f54d11dc5)</kbd>